# UIDocumentMenuViewController more button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentmenuvc

I have the code below in my app and when I click the "More" button, the dropbox option is displayed and disappear quickly, not allowing to enable.

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc]
                                            initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]
                                            inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    [picker addOptionWithTitle:@"Rolo de Câmera" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_photo_library"] order:0 handler:^{

    }];
    [picker addOptionWithTitle:@"Tirar Foto" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_photo_camera"] order:0 handler:^{

    }];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Result:

[image: DocumentPicker Bug]

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: Im seeing the same behaviour. Did you resolve this? Thnx!

Comment: @imobilizer nothing yet! :(

Comment: Thanks for the update! It just began to work for me (no code changes). AFAIK all that is changed is I have updated to iOS 10.3.3. There may have been an update to Dropbox version also but not sure. I hope you see the same!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `isTranslucent` property of `UINavigationBar`. I faced the same problem and I solved by removing this line in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions a similar code already exists:
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];

Comment: That's the cause of the problem. As I wrote, you have to remove this line!